# Why is this Sql Server CAST(..) rounding a Decimal to a VarChar?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting, rounding-error

I'm trying convert some `decimals` to `varchar`, but they are getting **rounded**.

Can someone tell me why?

```
declare @UpperLeftLatitude DECIMAL,
    @UpperLeftLongitude DECIMAL,
    @BottomRightLatitude DECIMAL,
    @BottomRightLongitude DECIMAL

SET @UpperLeftLatitude = 38.663
SET @UpperLeftLongitude = -122.857
SET @BottomRightLatitude = 37.795
SET @BottomRightLongitude = -121.219


DECLARE @SearchRectangleString VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SearchRectangleString = 'POLYGON((' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @UpperLeftLatitude) + ' ' + CAST(@UpperLeftLongitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' 
    + CAST(@BottomRightLatitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@UpperLeftLongitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' 
    + CAST(@BottomRightLatitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@BottomRightLongitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' 
    + CAST(@UpperLeftLatitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@BottomRightLongitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' 
    + CAST(@UpperLeftLatitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST(@UpperLeftLongitude AS VARCHAR(50)) + '))';

    SELECT @SearchRectangleString

-------------------
POLYGON((39 -123,38 -123,38 -121,39 -121,39 -123))

(1 row(s) affected)
```

*NOTE: Yes, I know my Lat/Longs are the wrong way around. I'll switch em soon.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your decimals are not specified with a length.  They aren't storing any decimal places.

Try the following:

```
 DECLARE @test DECIMAL, @test2 DECIMAL(8,4)
 SET @test = 12.3456
 SET @test2 = 12.3456

 SELECT @test, @test2
```

Comment: Far out brussel-sprout. U'd think after 15 years of doing Sql i'd pick that shiz up. Time to go home. Single Brain Cell in Brain very tired. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

As ck mentioned it gets rounded...

> When function is omitted or has a
>   value of 0 (default),
>   numeric_expression is **rounded**. When a
>   value other than 0 is specified,
>   numeric_expression is truncated.

Source: [ROUND (T-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)